# Pictures saved on sdcard on android

Tags: java, android

I had a problem when saving picture on sdcard from my app.
that when i am taking a picture and saving it on sdcard and go to my app and take a new one and save it on sdcard the previous preview picture appear and when view it on my computer it appear corrupted ?

why this problem ?

```
public static void save(Bitmap bm, String path) {
    OutputStream outStream = null;

    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        bm.recycle();
        System.gc();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

enter code here
```

Comment: You need the code that i am using to save the image ???

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, it is impossible for anyone to know what is wrong. More specifically, we need whatever code is necessary for us to help you solve the problem. Simply saying "i tried to save the picture but it is corrupted" isn't nearly enough information.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to store the image and display it.This is used to store the image

```
             //create new directory to store image    
             File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/files/Receipt"); 
             boolean success = false;
             if(!photo.exists())
             { 
                 success = photo.mkdirs(); 
             }
               //if exists save the image in specified path
             if(!success)
             {
                 dbimgguid = UUID.randomUUID();
                 imagename =dbimgguid.toString();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                 photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/files/Receipt", imagename+".png");
                 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photo));
                 imageurl = Uri.fromFile(photo); 
                 startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_RECEIPTREQUEST); 
             }
```

To view the image

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
     switch(requestCode)
     {
     case CAMERA_RECEIPTREQUEST:  
         if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK)
         {
         //Toast.makeText(this, "Receipt Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         options.inSampleSize = 8;
         ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         Bitmap receipt = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.toString(),options); 
         jpgView.setImageBitmap(receipt);                 

         } 
         break;
  }
```

I hope this will help you..
    }

Comment: Did you understand my problem @vino ????
because my problem is not how to save image and display it

Comment: Yeah.. I understand your problem. try this method then you can see the correct image with out any problems in the sdcard or pc..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions to store to the SD card?  I believe you need save and save to sd permissions.